# file upload from window to linux server using servlet jsp

Tags: java, linux, servlets, file-upload, tomcat7

i have tomcat server installed on linux machine .My webapp is deployed on linux machine and having browse functionality to browse the file.

Now my requirement is to **upload the browse file of window machine to linux server**,  in  given specified folder on linux using `servlet`.

I am using `sshxcute framework` for running the custom command.This framework provide the functionality to upload the file to linux server machine. i have tried running it through main class its working properly.

But when i tried to do the same thing using servlet jsp its not working because while browsing i am getting file name only, not the full path of a file.

Even if i hardcoded the path of file to  `ssh.uploadSingleDataToServer("C:/Users/MyPC/Documents/Youcam/apg.doc", "/home/cloudera/Desktop/Input");`on Servlet class and accessing my webapp to different window machine its uploading the file apg.doc in given folder,  but data of apg.doc is not coming why? please tell me where am i wrong on this approach or suggest me different approach thanks

Code through main class working fine

```
public class TestUpload{

public void upload(){
// Initialize a SSHExec instance without referring any object. 
SSHExec ssh = null;
// Wrap the whole execution jobs into try-catch block   
try {
    // Initialize a ConnBean object, parameter list is ip, username, password
    ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("9.125.71.115", "cloudera","cloudera");
    // Put the ConnBean instance as parameter for SSHExec static method getInstance(ConnBean) to retrieve a real SSHExec instance
    ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);              

    // Create a ExecShellScript, the reference class must be CustomTask
    CustomTask ct2 = new ExecShellScript("/home/cloudera/Desktop","./test.sh");
    // Connect to server
    ssh.connect();
    // Upload sshxcute_test.sh to /home/cloudera/Desktop/Input on remote system
    ssh.uploadSingleDataToServer("C:/Users/MyPC/Documents/Youcam/apg.doc", "/home/cloudera/Desktop/Input");
    // Execute task and get the returned Result object
    Result res = ssh.exec(ct2);
    // Check result and print out messages.
    if (res.isSuccess)
    {
        System.out.println("Return code: " + res.rc);
        System.out.println("sysout: " + res.sysout);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Return code: " + res.rc);
        System.out.println("error message: " + res.error_msg);
    }
} 
catch (TaskExecFailException e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally 
{
    ssh.disconnect();   
}
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
TestUpload te=new TestUpload();
te.upload();
}

}
```

THis is i tried from servlet not working

```
@WebServlet("/ImportController")
@MultipartConfig
public class ImportController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        // Create path components to save the file
        final String path = request.getParameter("destination");
        final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
        final String fileName = getFileName(filePart);

        //here i need the full path of file and file name but not sure wether sshUpload function will work

        sshUpload(fileName);

    }

    private String getFileName(final Part part) {
        final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
            for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return content.substring(
                        content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
            }
        }
        return null;

    public void sshUpload(String filepath)
    {
        // Initialize a SSHExec instance without referring any object. 
        SSHExec ssh = null;
        // Wrap the whole execution jobs into try-catch block   
        try {
            // Initialize a ConnBean object, parameter list is ip, username, password
            ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("9.125.71.115", "cloudera","cloudera");
            // Put the ConnBean instance as parameter for SSHExec static method getInstance(ConnBean) to retrieve a real SSHExec instance
            ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);              

            ssh.connect();
            // Upload sshxcute_test.sh to /home/tsadmin on remote system
            ssh.uploadSingleDataToServer(filepath, "/home/cloudera/Desktop/Input");
            // Execute task

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            ssh.disconnect();   
        }
}
```

THis is my jsp

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>File Upload</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            File:
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br/>
            Destination:
            <input type="text" value="/tmp" name="destination"/>
            </br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```